# How to fix this error at numerical integration?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

I have this:

```
ev = NSolve[-x == Tan[Pi*x] && 0 < x < 20, x] 
{{x -> 0.787637}, {x -> 1.67161}, {x -> 2.61621}, {x -> 
3.58655}, {x -> 4.56859}, {x -> 5.55668}, {x -> 6.54824}, {x -> 
7.54196}, {x -> 8.53712}, {x -> 9.53327}, {x -> 10.5301}, {x -> 
11.5275}, {x -> 12.5254}, {x -> 13.5235}, {x -> 14.5219}, {x -> 
15.5205}, {x -> 16.5192}, {x -> 17.5182}, {x -> 18.5172}, {x -> 
19.5163}}
c[j_] := Sin[Pi /. ev[[j]]/2]/
NIntegrate[(Sin[r*x /. ev[[j]]])^2, {r, 0, Pi}]
Table[c[j], {j, 10}]
ReplaceAll::reps: {(x->0.787637)/2} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
ReplaceAll::reps: {(x->1.67161)/2} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
ReplaceAll::reps: {(x->2.61621)/2} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
{0.532094 Sin[\[Pi] /. {(x -> 0.787637)/2}], 
 0.587346 Sin[\[Pi] /. {(x -> 1.67161)/2}], 
 0.611795 Sin[\[Pi] /. {(x -> 2.61621)/2}], 
 0.622331 Sin[\[Pi] /. {(x -> 3.58655)/2}], 
 0.627488 Sin[\[Pi] /. {(x -> 4.56859)/2}], 
 0.630326 Sin[\[Pi] /. {(x -> 5.55668)/2}], 
 0.632035 Sin[\[Pi] /. {(x -> 6.54824)/2}], 
 0.633138 Sin[\[Pi] /. {(x -> 7.54196)/2}], 
 0.633889 Sin[\[Pi] /. {(x -> 8.53712)/2}], 
 0.634422 Sin[\[Pi] /. {(x -> 9.53327)/2}]}
```

As you can see I got all those ReplaceAll::reps messages and expressions like

```
0.634422 Sin[\[Pi] /. {(x -> 9.53327)/2}]
```

How do I get simply numbers? The problem may be in c[j_]. Can you help?

Comment: `c[j_] := Sin[Pi x/2 /. ev[[j]]]/NIntegrate[(Sin[r*x /. ev[[j]]])^2, {r, 0, Pi}]`?

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Two problems

1. You needed `x` within the `Sin` expression
2. `ev[[j]]/2` was the other problem

One way around this is to use parenthesis.

```
c[j_] := Sin[Pi (x /. ev[[j]]) /2]/
  NIntegrate[(Sin[r*x /. ev[[j]]])^2, {r, 0, Pi}]
```

Now it works fine

```
Table[c[j], {j, 10}]
(* {0.502763, 0.289718, -0.503949, -0.376349, 0.488841, \
    0.404314, -0.479465, -0.417237, 0.473583, 0.42456} *)
```